# not Fill model When i Use HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i need to upload pic in asp mvc 5 .

but when i select image show me in `The UserPhoto field is required.` .

this my Code :

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase pic)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (pic != null)
            {
                pic = Request.Files[0];
                var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(pic.FileName);
                if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".jpeg")
                {
                    string filename = model.Name + model.PhoneNumber + ext;
                    pic.SaveAs(@"~/Image/" + filename);
                    model.UserPhoto = filename;
                }
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser { Name = model.Name, Family = model.Family, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber, UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};

            user.UserPhoto=model.UserPhoto;
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

`HttpPostedFileBase pic` is have value but model is null .

how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, it seems you mean `model.UserPhoto` is null, since `model` very clearly does have a value, as do most of its properties, except `UserPhoto`.

The question, then, is are you posting something with the name `UserPhoto` in your form? If not, then of course it's null. The only things that will be set after post are properties that were actually posted. Anything else will be either null or the default value of the type, if it's non-nullable (i.e. `0` for `int`).

However, you shouldn't need it. First, this appears to be a "create" view, so `UserPhoto` will have no value to begin with. If `pic` is set, you will set `UserPhoto` to that, otherwise, nothing was uploaded, and `UserPhoto` *should be null*. If this were an "edit" view, though, you would merely pull a copy of the user from the database first (which will include the current `UserPhoto`). You would only change it, again, if `pic` were posted.

**EDIT**

The error is because you have `UserPhoto` set as required. Just remove that validation. Or, you can simply get rid of `pic` and post directly to `UserPhoto`.

Comment: in form name is  pic but un controller name is userphoto , thanks

Comment: No. In controller the name is `pic` as well, because you have that as a param. Regardless, the form and action param/model property name has to match up. If you want the value to go into `UserPhoto` then your input in your form has to be named `UserPhoto` as well.